# Is there a version of numpy.dot() that doesn't "collapse" the matrix?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have *a*, an n x 1 vector, and *b*, an n x n matrix. What I want to do is similar to np.dot(a, b) but without the last step of collapsing the matrix to another 1 x n vector by summing the elements of each column. Another way to look at it is that it is similar to simply going a*b, but rather than mutiplying the elements of *a* by each column of the matrix we want to do it by row. An example would help explain what I mean:

```
a = np.array([-1, 2, 1])

b = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

What I want is the matrix:

```
a * b = np.array([[-1, -2, -3], [8, 10, 12], [7, 8, 9]])
```

Kind of like considering *b* to be an n x 1 vector as well but where each of its elements happens to be another vector.

This feels really easy, but I can't seem to work out how to do it.

Note: would rather not include a loop in this if avoidable, just for efficiency (n can get really high).

I've had a look at most versions of multiplication in numpy. The loop to do it is trivial, but I did that too and its not going to work for large n.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `dot` - there's not sum-of-products.  You want a element-wise multiplication, of a (3,1) with the (3,3):

```
In [164]: a[:,None]*b
Out[164]: 
array([[-1, -2, -3],
       [ 8, 10, 12],
       [ 7,  8,  9]])
```

`a` is (3,) shape; in multiplication like this it is treated as (1,3), resulting in:

```
In [163]: a*b
Out[163]: 
array([[-1,  4,  3],
       [-4, 10,  6],
       [-7, 16,  9]])
```

The key concept is `broadcasting`.